# Short-circuit Postgres query after specific value has been returned

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently have a query of the form:

```
SELECT myFunc(col1) FROM myTable;
```

`myFunc` returns a `bool` value. Is it possible to short-circuit query execution so that the query will end the first time `myFunc` returns a row with the value `true`? It doesn't matter the order in which the query is executed, simply that one execution of the function has been found to be `true`.

[`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-subquery.html) doesn't work since it only tests whether or not there are rows returned at all; but `myFunc` always returns a value (`true` or `false`), so `EXISTS` wouldn't be helpful in identifying the above stopping condition.

Comment: What is `myFunc` doing? Is it particularly slow?

Comment: Why can't you use exists and `where myFunc(col1)`?

Comment: @JasonGoematt as noted above, `myFunc` returns a value regardless (`true` or `false`); `EXISTS` tests whether *any* row is returned. `EXISTS` will always returns `true` for a column evaluated with `myFunc` even if `myFunc` is always returning `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```sql
select mf 
from (SELECT myFunc(col1) as mf FROM myTable) t 
where mf limit 1;
```

I think that the optimizer will flatten the query and do exactly what you need.

Or using `exists` as @JasonGoemaat suggests:

```sql
select exists 
(
 select from myTable where myFunc(col1)
);
```

Comment: The subquery of your second suggestion will process all the rows in `myTable` to return a result set where the function returns true, the `exists` only converts that result in to a `1` or `0` but does not make it any more efficient.

Comment: I believe that it's smart enough to flatten and stop after the first hit. Worth trying though.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm `where mf limit 1` does not solve the problem. `myFunc` will *always* return either `true` or `false`. So even if all evaluations of `myFunc` return `false`, the above query will return immediately. But the goal of the above question is to return early if there is at least one `true` evaluation of `myFunc`.

Comment: The only way to stop a query processing all rows is with `limit`, [from the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html): "As soon as MySQL has sent the required number of rows to the client, it aborts the query"

Comment: `where mf limit 1` will stop the evaluation only after the first result row is yielded, i.e. as required. `where mf` is the same as `where mf = true` but w/o tautology. `exists` will cause evaluating to stop right after the first `true` evaluation of the `where` expression, i.e. as required. @Tony Postgresql please, not MySQL.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm - Apologies, my mistake. I'm not sure why I thought the question was for MySQL... I see in the docs it says "The subquery will _generally_ only be executed far enough to determine whether at least one row is returned" which seems a bit vague, I wonder in what situations it does not short circuit.

Comment: @Tony Cheers. Maybe certain `order by` cases when the outcome is not clear until late?

Answer (score 0):

I think using `exists` with a where clause and limit on the subquery should be pretty efficient:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE myFunc(col1) LIMIT 1);
```

If you don't mind checking for an empty result set when no instances of `myFunc` return `true` then you could leave off the `exists` check.

I'd be interested to know if putting `myfunc(col1)` as a computed field in a view and selecting from the view is any faster; but as
you don't say what the `myFunc` is doing it's hard to be sure which method is best without testing.

Comment: `myFunc` will *always* return either `true` or `false`, so using `LIMIT 1` could easily indicate 'success' even though actually a `false` value was returned.

Comment: @ChaimKut - no, that's what the `where myFunc(col1)` comes in. It restricts the query to only those rows where the result is `true` and ends the query with `limit` as soon as one result is true.

Comment: @ChaimKut - what does `myFunc` do, how slow is it, and how many rows are there in your table? and more importantly, is the query too slow or are you anticipating a speed issue in the future? In which case there might be other ways to speed this up without using a function.